# Reading space separated values file in c++ error

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to get float values out of a file to use them in my program. I used the following forum to construct the program [Read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/c-read-file-line-by-line).
But the values obtained by doing so appear to be truncated at the end.

My code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

ifstream file;
file.open("test_file.ssv");
string line;
while(file.good() && (getline(file, line)))
{
    istringstream iss(line);
    double a, b, c;
    iss >> a >> b >>c ;
    cout << a <<endl;
}
file.close();
return (0);
}
```

The output that I obtain is

```
9292.31
32432.2
```

While my file has the following data

```
9292.3123 4234.66 342.25423
32432.2423 3423.656 341.67841
```

Any suggestions to improve upon this?

Comment: Thry this: `cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;`

Comment: @juanchopanza No help and it is rounding up the values not truncating them the output from your suggestion `9292.31 4234.66 342.254   
32432.2 3423.66 341.678`

Comment: Note that the sentence `file.close()` sentence is not needed. The stream closes the file at the end of its lifetime. Read about RAII: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Comment: +1 Noobie C++ code without C-style io. Only C++. Well done.

Comment: Well, you didn't clearly say what the problem was. You should state the issue more clearly.

Comment: @Manu343726 On the other hand, it doesn't hurt (and you do have to explicitly close output, because you have to check its status after the close).

Comment: I might mention that the test `file.good()` in the `while` isn't necessary.  If that condition is false, `getline` (and every other input operation) is a no-op, and returns false.

Comment: You should drop the `#include <cstring>` and use `#include <string>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your standard stream may have a low floating point precision and you therefore only see a few of the decimals when outputing a `float` with `std::cout`. Use `std::ios_base::precision` to increase the precision and look into using `std:: ios::floatfield` to output fixed or scientific precision , example:

```
// modify precision
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::ios

    int main () {
      double f = 3.14159;
      std::cout.unsetf ( std::ios::floatfield );                // floatfield not set
      std::cout.precision(5);
      std::cout << f << '\n';
      std::cout.precision(10);
      std::cout << f << '\n';
      std::cout.setf( std::ios::fixed, std:: ios::floatfield ); // floatfield set to fixed
      std::cout << f << '\n';
      return 0;
    }
```

Outputs:

> 3.1416
>   3.14159
>   3.1415900000

Comment: I agree with precision being the issue.

Comment: You might actually describe what your doing, particularly with `floatfield`.

Comment: @JamesKanze I have added more explanations to the post now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem in the precision of the `cout`.
Try to test the comparison:

```
cout << "Stand.: " << a << "  Prec.: " << fixed << setprecision(10) << a << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below will make some improvement.

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << a << std::endl;
```

Reference to the two links below for more information:  
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/ 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

Happy coding with C++.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has been truncated.  You can't truncate a `double`; it
always has the same number of bits and the same format.  But
you're outputting using the default precision (6) and the
default format, which will always output 6 significant digits,
and no more.

There are two issues here.  The first is simple: what format and
precision do you want?  There are three possible formats: the
default (which will use either fixed or scientific, depending on
the value, and for which the precision signifies the maximun
number of significant digits), fixed , or scientific (where the
precision signifies the number of digits after the decimal).
Thus, with a precision of 6, depending on the format, your first
value will be:

```
default:    9292.31
fixed:      9292.312300
scientific: 9.292312E03
```

For the values you show, fixed would seem most appropriate; but
if you have very small values, it will display less digits, and
for very large values, you can get some very long strings.

The usual way of handling this is to define a manipulator for
whatever the values represent; in this case, I'll just call it
`values`, because I don't know anything more precise about your
application, but you should probably find a more meaningful
name:

```
class value
{
    mutable std::ostream* myOwner;
    mutable std::ios_base::fmtflags myFlags;
    mutable int myPrecision;
    void capture( std::ostream& owner )
    {
        if ( myOwner == NULL ) {
            myOwner = &owner;
            myFlags = myOwner->fmtflags();
            myPrecision= myOwner->precision();
        }
    }
public:
    value() : myOwner( NULL ) {}
    ~value()
    {
        if ( myOwner != NULL ) {
            myOwner->flags( myFlags );
            myOwner->precision( myPrecision );
        }
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest, value const& manip )
    {
        manip.capture( dest );
        dest.setf( std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield );
        dest.precision( 6 );
    }
};
```

This will also restore the formatting status at the end of the
full expression (since it should only be used as a temporary);
this is generally a good idea becaues it prevents surprises in
later code.  If you're doing any significant output, you'll
create a base class for the save and restore, and derive your
actual manipulator from that.

Once you have this, you can write:

```
std::cout << value() << a << " " << b << " " << c << std::endl;
```

All of the values after `value()` in the statement will be
output with the desired format.

More generally, do you understand how machine floating point
works?  The actual values stored in your doubles will *not* be
those that you see in the file, because those that you see in
the file are not representable in the usual double format.  For
the number of digits you enter, you should not see any
difference if you output the same number of digits, or even one
or two more, but if you output a very large number of digits
(say about 17) you could.

Comment: explicit cast to integer is generally known as a truncating conversion.

Comment: @Frodo Yes, but it's a conversion.  The double itself isn't changed.  (But I can see that my wording might be ambiguous here.)

Comment: `You can't truncate a double.` Actually, you _can_ trucate the value contained within a IEEE `double` or `float`. See [Loss of significance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) for more information on the subject.